# Scope of variable changed inside Future's OnSuccess call

Tags: scala, scope, akka

I need to get back a variable that was changed inside a Future's onSuccess block. Here is my sample code.

```
def futureFunction(arg:Any):Any = { 
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(10 seconds) 
  var ret:Any = None
  val f: Future[Any] = someActor ? arg
    f.onSuccess {
      case a:String => {
        ret = 1 
        println(ret) //prints "1" 
      }
      case a:Int => { 
        ret = 2 
        println(ret) //prints "2"
      }
    }
  ret //returns None
  }
```

`ret` returns as None and does not change to `1` or `2`. So does this mean that value of variable `ret` inside the onSuccess block cannot be returned? Yet, this seems to work:

```
var a : Any = None

{
  a = 1
  println("inside "+ a ) //prints "inside 1"
}

println(a)   // prints "1"
```

What can I do in the future onSuccess block so that  value of `ret` is returned as `1`or `2` depending on whether the future's result is an integer or a string? What are the scoping rules in this case for scala. (I am using akka). Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is not of scoping but of timing.

1. First you're initializing `ret` to `None`.
2. Then you're sending the message `arg` to `someActor`, which returns a future.
3. After that, you set up a function to be called when the future completes, which, if all goes well, will assign a value of 1 or 2 to `ret` at some point in the future.
4. Last of all, you immediately return the value of `ret`, which is still `None`.
5. And at some point in the future, the future completes, and your onSuccess function runs changing the value of `ret` and then printing it. But of course that can't go back in time and change the value that was already returned earlier.

So, to answer your question, there is nothing you can do in the onSuccess that will go back in time and change the already returned value. There are two alternatives though. One alternative would be to block until the future completes, then determine whether to return 1 or 2. The other is to return a `Future[Int]` so the caller can decide whether or not they want to block on the result. The code for that is actually simpler than what you have:

`def futureFunction(arg:Any):Future[Int] = { 
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(10 seconds) 
  val f: Future[Any] = someActor ? arg
  f.map {
    case a:String => 1
    case a:Int => 2
  }
}`

If you do need to block, you can use `Await.result`, either inside or outside futureFunction depending on where you want to block.

Comment: accepted answer because of clear explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In `futureFunction`, `ret` is returned before the `onSuccess` handler runs. `ret` will become `1` or `2` when that happens, but it is too late at that point.

What you want to use is `Future.map`

```
someActor ? arg map {
  case a:String => 1
  case a:Int => 2 
}
```

Note that `futureFunction` will either have to return a `Future`, or you will have to make a call to `Await.result` inside the function to block until the result is available.

Comment: Will the call to future and its subsequent return of the result still be asynchronous? or would your code above make the process a blocking call? if so why? Please elaborate. Thanks.

Comment: @1xQ http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.2/scala/actors.html#Ask__Send-And-Receive-Future

Comment: As long as `futureFunction` returns a `Future` it is non-blocking. `Await.result` is explicitly blocking.